# How to check if new data is added in my dabatabase using php?

Tags: php, mysql

How to check if new data is added in my database using php? I have a database that accept new users. I want to be notified if new user is added on the database? My idea is to add a new table in my db that will count and save the old number of users and then check if the old value is the same of new count. But I don't want to add a table just for saving the number of users. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Date stamp additions check with cron job for new

Comment: Or, why not just send a e-mail in the same function / code that registers the new users?

Comment: @Abdulla : There's nothing to show, I just want to know the way on how to solve it.

Comment: @Dagon : Thanks I'll try it.

Comment: @Epodax: I already have the email function to send the new user. But I want to have a notification inside the system so that I could use it in my condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can check like this and you can also check last insert id using      `last_insert_id`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        $last_id = last_insert_id;
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error();
    }
```

Comment: @Ravider Kumar: Thanks, but it will not work. What I want is that: I want to have a notification on my system that new user is added on the database. So if my db count now is 1000, and after 1 hour it's 1001 already so notification will show in my admin account "new user has registered."

Comment: do you want to email notification after new user registration?

Comment: Yes I do have. @Epodax already ask me that on the comments. I need to have a notification only inside the system.

Comment: then you can get last record form user table to show notification in admin like: SELECT username FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: Thanks, but again the logic what I wanted is not there. You only suggesting on how to get the latest id. Again: I want like this. if db count now is 1000, and after 1 hour it's 1001 already so notification will show in my admin account "new user has registered." I don't need the information of new registered. I just need to know that there was a new data being added.

Comment: ok then add new field in user table view or not (0 and 1) and get count of row where count is 0(not viewed ) (eg. if 0 count is 3 then 3 new user subscribed ) and on try to update count to 1 on user list page or on view notification click.